# Get Two from One

Tags: math, code-challenge, game, graph-theory, atomic-code-golf

As we saw in [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154265/hexcellent-minesweeping) complex logical statements can be expressed in terms of the simple connectives of generalized Minesweeper.  However Generalized minesweeper still has redundancies.

In order to avoid these redundancies we define a new game called "Generalized-1 Minesweeper".

Generalized-1 Minesweeper is a version Minesweeper played on an arbitrary graph.  The graph has two types of vertex, an "indicator" or a "value".  A value can be either on or off (a mine or a dud) however its state is unknown to the player. An indicator tells that exactly one of the adjacent cells is on (a mine).  Indicators do not count as mines themselves.

For example the following board for Generalized Minesweeper tells us that cells A and B are either both mines or neither of them are mines.

[image: Simple game]

*(In the diagram indicators are marked in gray while values are white)*

Unlike in normal minesweeper where you click values that are off to reveal indicators, there is no such mechanic in Generalized Minesweeper.  A player simply determines for what states of the graph can satisfy its indicators.

Your goal is to make a `2` in Generalized-1 Minesweeper.
You will build a structure in Generalized-1 Minesweeper such that there are 8 specific cells for which all possible configurations of values have *exactly* two cells on.  This means it behaves exactly as the `2` does in traditional minesweeper.  When you write your solution you should not have specific values in mind for value cells. (In answer to H.PWiz's question it is allowed that some value cells might be deducible from the state)

### Scoring

You answers will be scored by the number of vertices in the final graph minus 8 (for the 8 inputs) with a lower score being better.  If two answers tie in this metric the tie breaker will be the number of edges.

Comment: Does any edge always connect an indicator vertex and a value vertex?

Comment: @xnor In order to maximize your score they ought, but I don't feel like I need to make that a rule.  Edges that don't connect values to indicators don't change the behavior of the graph.

Comment: When 6 is subtracted from the score, what are the 6 inputs? Aren't there 8 cells?

Comment: @xnor Sorry should be 8.  Fixed now.

Comment: What do you mean by "structure...such that there are 8 specific cells that the only possible configurations of values have exactly two cells on."? Are the only possible configurations supposed to have only two mines?

Comment: @dylnan You should be building a graph such that for 8 of its value cells (you choose which) exactly 2 of them must be mines, and any two of them can be mines.  The graph can have other helper value cells as well but we are only concerned with the behavior of 8 of the graph's cells.  Does that clarify?  I can help if you have any further specific questions.

Comment: Thanks, that does help. Is it required that any possible choice of two cells being mines (in the set of 8) satisfies the graph?

Comment: @dylnan Yes it is.

Comment: I'm not convinced that, in this case, `you can always improve your score by removing such cells`. This is certainly true when you can just change the indicator cell attached, but here there is only one kind of indicator cell

Comment: @H.PWiz You might be correct.  I'll see about verifying this fact but until then I will remove the comment.

Comment: @H.PWiz The only reason that can't be reduced is because you can deduce the value of the input cells.  I think that we can actually can remove deducible cells as long as they do not also deduce our input cells.

Answer (score 7):

### 42 vertices, 56 edges

[image: Mines network]

Each variable is a value vertex, and each box is an indicator vertex with edges to the variables inside it. The inputs are *x<sub>1</sub>*, ..., *x<sub>8</sub>*. For example, here's a solution with mines at *x<sub>3</sub>* and *x<sub>5</sub>*, with mines highlighted in green.

[image: Mines network solution]

The horizontal constraints ensure that exactly one of the *a*'s and exactly one of the *b*'s has a mine. In those two columns, *r* does not hold a mine, but it does in the other six columns. (Note that *a* and *b* can't both have a mine in the same column.) Each input *x* is opposite the *r* in its column, so exactly two inputs have mines as desired.

For `k` inputs, this uses `5k+2` vertices (`3k` value and `2k+2` indicator), and `7k` edges. Here, `k=8` inputs gives 42 vertices and 56 edges.

Answer (score 3):

## 50 Vertices, 89 edges

Based on the logic gate from H.PWiz's answer.

```
  A&B      C&D      E&F      G&H
   |        |        |        |
b--1--a  d--1--c  f--1--e  h--1--g
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
1--?--1  1--?--1  1--?--1  1--?--1
|     |  |     |  |     |  |     |
A     B  C     D  E     F  G     H
```

Each `*` is on when the two respective inputs are on. To handle the case of a single input, we use the intermediate values `a=A&!B` etc. Connecting all three values `a`, `b` and `A&B` to the input of a secondary level of gates gives us an effective input of `A|B` (this saves vertices over `!(!A&!B)`):

```
      *              *
      |              |
   #--1--#        #--1--#
   |  |  |        |  |  |
   1--?--1        1--?--1
  |||   |||      |||   |||
  A|B   C|D      E|F   G|H
```

These `*`s are on if two of their inputs (corresponding to four of the original inputs) are on, except in the case of the pairs already covered above. Meanwhile, we can connect the `#*#` nodes to a final gate. We therefore have the following results:

```
A&B
C&D
E&F
G&H
(A|B)&(C|D)         [4 cases]
(E|F)&(G|H)         [4 cases]
(A|B|C|D)&(E|F|G|H) [16 cases]
```

These cover all 28 of the cases of two inputs. It then remains to connect a final indicator to these seven values. If fewer than two inputs are on, then none of these will be on, so the indicator will be off. If more than two inputs are on, then more than one of these will be on, and the indicator will be off.

Comment: Ah, I had similar idea, but ended up creating a more complicated version of this. Good job!

Comment: I'm not convinced that there are 43 vertices. You clearly show 42, so you're saying you only need one more to connect it all up?

Comment: Actually, if I have drawn correctly the graph you describe, I think it allows for states like `ACE`, `BDF`, `ADG` ...

Comment: @H.PWiz I see what you mean... I think maybe I can solve that with extra edges to give the expression `(a&b)+((a|b)&(c|d))+(c&d)+((a|b|c|d)&(e|f|g|h))+(e&f)+((e|f)&(g|h))+(g&h)==1`, does that look right to you?

Comment: Maybe, although to me that expression looks like it solves the problem entirely. And I have no idea what edges you can add to get that...

Answer (score 2):

## 197 Vertices, 308 edges

I came up with this answer last night, but withheld posting it because it was such a high score. However, since it beats the [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154590/71256) by so much, I though I should post it.

I use the following set up on all 28 pairs of values cells in `ABCDEFGH`

```
   ?*
   |
?--1--?
|  |  |
1--?--1
|     |
A     B
```

`?` represents an value cell not in `ABCDEFGH`. Here, when `?*` is **ON**, `A` and `B` are both on. Otherwise, `A` and `B` could be in any other configuration.

I connect all 28 `?*`s to one indicator cell. This means that only one pair in `ABCDEFGH` will have two **ON**. Which is sufficient to enforce that exactly two of my output cells will be **ON**

Comment: Note that in the gate you have each of the 4 `?`s corresponds to one of the 4 states of `A B`.

Comment: @HeebyJeebyMan Interesting, I hadn't considered that. I just found this gate by luck

Answer (score 1):

## 354 nodes, 428 edges

Just to prove it's possible. I will improve this later with some caching.

(hopefully no code error)

I tried to write a Mathematica program [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42619492#42619492) to check program validity, but it doesn't work probably because there are too many variables.

The result was generated by computer program: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRdb5swFH3Gv@JKkYpRabYk7TpV2572MmlKX/oWRcgEh1ARGxnTJeqav55dG4Mpbfd08fG5536ZWx31TorF@VzsK6k01MeakE3J6hqWMuN3JGhEU/MMvsOMBIXIig3TUtV4Xq1JwLOcu28STKAyfgx0U5X8U1nUGuQWBOogWoPecaAse4yAqbzZc6EN2muSIONbSJJCFDpJgNa83MaAfNRfSsEjTCYw4PSJlQ23aManbX54NTjBpUkXsWJrBIxje@0LmLKq4iKjXjAyrK1UcMCcercAS@LYmIOLKqQ21yM1mEDG0yYHKcqjdbME254u0iBU3MlFEfFlP2GcJLE0W6viulEmlDZiLU7MECxxwzY704Tnl48VwjCE3zLHJEtY3j9MAQHXFsMZFeNlbeV4mVhW22gadV2kbjQdwRbRN9irrMzlGt074vus7tYwLWtY@ruSrmeyoiyGtK/UOdETgws4pTHYD7TdmcFB4HzTqG/EJoYsBpyHrzL@wJKueIxp3CKPpBbhA8SJtp2ZwMP9z3toB6Z3hchr2HHF8bFsOPyCbZE35tRo2Mk/vnrqs/PPhIkMJ9zX7ahsis04pdFqvu6ZUr1DPFkmEj974uH/zAUymfnH2z6A@UUS82wUEzmnX6M1vv5CVI3G1aGQSCk6YwD4C2w1a83tOjJDoBa/QGA@Bq4tQJ3jqfecv8LN2Zo3dB9h1gouxsBt5@KUF625GWc4HyZkgEUL3IyBXvDa5eAYbPUFP/5C14cLV461c2cXzl6vnejNSPRVXlaSTMBtI0Xad6Zi88QqVQhNw@cQLiGMIZw@ykJQEoTPL/Dt6geuiHCKU9szTQ8xHCMgds@5Q7cA7LIikdF4CXvV0aLz0ZbNPuWqX/B3wyiDVXw1wwzfuNhYr1xKLqhPI0Kn8/kf)

---

I use a gate that looks like this:

```
               (f)
                |
                |
               (#)
              /   \
             /     \
           (d)     (e)
          /           \
         /             \
       (#) --- (c) --- (#)
     .'                  '.
   .'                      '.
(a)                          (b)
```

where `(#)` are 1-indicators, `(a)` .. `(f)` are values.

Then,

```
c = (not a) and (not b)
d = (not a) and      b
e =      a  and (not b)
f =      a  xnor     b
```

Also, this gate

```
(a) ----- (#) ----- (b)
```

gives

```
b = not a
```

. Use those two types of gates you can build any expressions.

Of course, this one is for asserting that `(a)` must be true:

```
(a) ----- (#)
```

Answer (score 1):

### 81 Nodes, 108 Edges

Using 13 nodes and 14 edges, we create the following Adder gate (C(arry) = X AND Y, S(um) = X XOR Y):

```
X--1--------------?
   |              |
   ?--1--S--1--?--1
   |  |           |
   |  C           |
Y--1--------------?
```

Use four Adders M1, M2, M3, M4 to add A+B, C+D, E+F, G+H, respectively, with the resulting carry C1, C2, C3, C4, and sum S1, S2, S3, S4.

Use two Adders M5, M6 to add S1+S2, S3+S4, with the resulting carry C5, C6, and sum S5, S6.

Use one Adder M7 to add S5+S6 to get C7 and S7.

Now connect all carries to a single indicator node like the following:

```
C1-|
C2-|
C3-|
C4-+-1
C5-|
C6-|
C7-|
```

and force S7 (the modulo 2 of sum of 8 values) to be 0 by this circuit:

```
S7--1--?--1
```

I argue that this circuit forces exactly two values from `ABCDEFGH` to be ON, since it can only be an even number (since S7 is 0), and there cannot be more than 3 ON values (since only one of C1-C7 is ON).